# Why the sync code is running after the macrotask

Tags: javascript, event-loop

As my understanding about event loop, event loop will push the callbacks into the callstack, but for example, the following code, the sync code `console.log(2)` is running after the click event handler, why is that?

```js
console.log(1)

document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(3)
})

document.body.click()

console.log(2)
```

Comment: `document.body.click()`  I don't believe goes via the event pump, you would need to dispatch the click event instead..

Answer (score 0):

By doing :

```js
console.log(1)

document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(3)
})

document.body.click()

console.log(2)
```

The result is :

```
1
3
2
```

But by doing :

```js
console.log(1)

document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
    setTimeout( () => {
        console.log(3)
    },200);
})

document.body.click()

console.log(2)
```

The result is :

```
1
2
3
```

So my conclusions are that the click event is well put in the stack, but that it unstacks instantly.

Comment: Or maybe the `eventClick` is not put in the stack while the `setTimeout()` is.

Comment: From my previous understanding, the click handler will be pushed into the task queue, and after the callstack is empty and the job queue is empty, the task in task queue will be running. I m confused about this.

Comment: THIS IS VERY CONFUSING...

Comment: "*the click event is well put in the stack*" doesn't make sense. Only function calls are placed on the stack, not events.